# Woocommerce rest api authentication

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I enable woocommerce rest api and generate consumer_key and consumer_secret and use basic authentication under https. but I get 401 (unauthorized) status code.
How to can be authorized?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Woocommerce rest api uses `oAuth 1.0` so you have to pass these authorization to work with woocommerce rest api

for example :

```
your endpoint : https://example.com/wc-api/v3/products

method : get

Authorization : oauth 1.o

consumer key : your_consumer_key
consumer secret : your_consumer_secret

then try to get data in postman using `oauth 1.0`

hope this will help
```

Comment: I try oath method and basic auth method but I get same result. 401 status!

Comment: will you share screenshot of backend with api settings

Comment: so i can help you further

Comment: how to do the same thing in angular